# JQuery on click of button, scroll down and animate graph with Waypoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-waypoints

I have two graphs that I am animating on click of a button:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oLwGWq

So basically on click of the first button I want to scroll down and have the first graph animate.

On click of the second button I want to scroll down again, have the first graph hidden and then animate the second graph.

The problem I'm having is both of the graphs only animate the fist time you click the button, how can I get them to animate every time a button is clicked?

The other problem I'm having is the labels above the graph are flickering when you scroll up and down. How can I keep them from flickering? For the scrolling action I'm using [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/).

You can view my full code at the above CodePen link, here's my js:

```
$('#q-graph').css('opacity', 0);
$('.label, .label2').hide();
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#q2-fade').hide();
//navigation functionality
$("#graph1").click(function (){
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#graphs-container").offset().top
  }, 1000);
  $('#q2-fade,  #q3-fade,  #q4-fade,  #q5-fade,  #q6-fade, #q7-fade, #title2, #title3, #title4, #title5, #title6, #title7, #title8, .label').hide();
  $('#q-fade').fadeIn('slow', function(){
    $('#q-graph').waypoint(function(direction) {
      if (direction === 'down') {
        $('#q-graph').addClass('animated fadeIn');
        $("#q-graph td#one").animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
        $("#q-graph td#two").delay(100).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
        $("#q-graph td#three").delay(120).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
        $("#q-graph td#four").delay(140).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
        $("#q-graph td#five").delay(160).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
        $("#q-graph td#six").delay(180).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
        $("#q-graph td#seven").delay(200).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
        $("#q-graph td#eight").delay(220).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
        $("#q-graph td#nine").delay(240).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
        $("#q-graph td#ten").delay(260).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
        $("#q-graph td#eleven").delay(280).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
        $("#q-graph td#twelve").delay(300).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
        $("#q-graph td#thirteen").delay(320).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
        $("#q-graph td#fourteen").delay(340).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
        $("#q-graph td#fifteen").delay(360).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
        $("#q-graph td#sixteen").delay(380).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
        $('.label').delay(400).fadeIn('slow');
      }
    }, {
      offset: '10%'
    });
  });
});
$("#graph2").click(function (){
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#graphs-container").offset().top
  }, 1000);
  $('#q-fade,#q3-fade,#q4-fade,#q5-fade,#q6-fade,#q7-fade, #title1, #title3, #title4, #title5, #title6, #title7, #title8').fadeOut('fast', function(){
    $('#q2-fade').fadeIn('slow', function(){
      $('#q2-graph').waypoint(function() {
        $('#q2-graph').addClass('animated fadeIn');
        $("#q2-graph td#one").animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
        $("#q2-graph td#two").delay(100).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
        $("#q2-graph td#three").delay(120).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
        $("#q2-graph td#four").delay(140).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
        $("#q2-graph td#five").delay(160).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
        $("#q2-graph td#six").delay(180).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
        $('.label2').delay(200).fadeIn('slow');

      }, { offset: '10%' });
    });

  });
});
});
```

I'm also sure there's a much, much easier and cleaner way to animate these graphs other than using delay, but I still have a lot to learn about JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your points of interest are in the following two functions:

```
$("#graph1").click(function (){
```

and

```
$("#graph2").click(function (){
```

The first action you need to do is to reset the effect of animation and then you can proceed with your code otherwise on successive clicks you will obtain the unwanted result.

My snippet (look for my comments "// reset the animatoin effects......"):

```js
$(function () {
  $('#q-graph').css('opacity', 0);
  $('.label, .label2').hide();
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#q2-fade').hide();
    //navigation functionality
    $("#graph1").click(function (){
      // reset the animatoin effects......
      $('#q-graph').removeClass('animated fadeIn');
      $("#q-graph td#one").css({height:"0%"});
      $("#q-graph td#two").css({height:"0%"});
      $("#q-graph td#three").css({height:"0%"});
      $("#q-graph td#four").css({height:"0%"});
      $("#q-graph td#five").css({height:"0%"});
      $("#q-graph td#six").css({height:"0%"});
      $("#q-graph td#seven").css({height:"0%"});
      $("#q-graph td#eight").css({height:"0%"});
      $("#q-graph td#nine").css({height:"0%"});
      $("#q-graph td#ten").css({height:"0%"});
      $("#q-graph td#eleven").css({height:"0%"});
      $("#q-graph td#twelve").css({height:"0%"});
      $("#q-graph td#thirteen").css({height:"0%"});
      $("#q-graph td#fourteen").css({height:"0%"});
      $("#q-graph td#fifteen").css({height:"0%"});
      $("#q-graph td#sixteen").css({height:"0%"});
      // reset the animatoin effects......ENDS


      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#graphs-container").offset().top
      }, 1000);
      $('#q2-fade,  #q3-fade,  #q4-fade,  #q5-fade,  #q6-fade, #q7-fade, #title2, #title3, #title4, #title5, #title6, #title7, #title8, .label').hide();
      $('#q2-fade').show();
      $('#q-fade').fadeIn('slow', function(){
        $('#q-graph').waypoint(function(direction) {
          if (direction === 'down') {
            $('#q-graph').addClass('animated fadeIn');
            $("#q-graph td#one").animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
            $("#q-graph td#two").delay(100).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
            $("#q-graph td#three").delay(120).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
            $("#q-graph td#four").delay(140).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
            $("#q-graph td#five").delay(160).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
            $("#q-graph td#six").delay(180).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
            $("#q-graph td#seven").delay(200).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
            $("#q-graph td#eight").delay(220).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
            $("#q-graph td#nine").delay(240).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
            $("#q-graph td#ten").delay(260).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
            $("#q-graph td#eleven").delay(280).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
            $("#q-graph td#twelve").delay(300).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
            $("#q-graph td#thirteen").delay(320).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
            $("#q-graph td#fourteen").delay(340).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
            $("#q-graph td#fifteen").delay(360).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
            $("#q-graph td#sixteen").delay(380).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
            $('.label').delay(400).fadeIn('slow');
          }
        }, {
          offset: '10%'
        });
      });
    });
    $("#graph2").click(function (){
      // reset the animatoin effects......
      $('#q2-graph').removeClass('animated fadeIn');
      $("#q2-graph td#one").css({height:"0%"});
      $("#q2-graph td#two").css({height:"0%"});
      $("#q2-graph td#three").css({height:"0%"});
      $("#q2-graph td#four").css({height:"0%"});
      $("#q2-graph td#five").css({height:"0%"});
      $("#q2-graph td#six").css({height:"0%"});
      // reset the animatoin effects......ENDS



      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#graphs-container").offset().top
      }, 1000);
      $('#q-fade,#q3-fade,#q4-fade,#q5-fade,#q6-fade,#q7-fade, #title1, #title3, #title4, #title5, #title6, #title7, #title8').fadeOut('fast', function(){
        $('#q2-fade').fadeIn('slow', function(){
          $('#q2-graph').waypoint(function() {
            $('#q2-graph').addClass('animated fadeIn');
            $("#q2-graph td#one").animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
            $("#q2-graph td#two").delay(100).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
            $("#q2-graph td#three").delay(120).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
            $("#q2-graph td#four").delay(140).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
            $("#q2-graph td#five").delay(160).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
            $("#q2-graph td#six").delay(180).animate({height:"100%"}, 300, "linear");
            $('.label2').delay(200).fadeIn('slow');

          }, { offset: '10%' });
        });

      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
.label, .label2{
  color: #333333 !important;
}
#intro{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align:center;
  color: #333333 !important;
  width:100%;
  min-height:10em;
  margin:0;
  padding-top:10px;
}
button{
  padding: 1em 2em;
  font-family: 'Montserrat',sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  font-size: 1em;
  border:0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}
button:hover{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
#q-graph {
  display: block;
  /* fixes layout wonkiness in FF1.5 */
  position: relative;
  width: 850px;
  height: 404px;
  margin: 1.1em 0 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 11px;
  z-index: 3;
  color: #333333;
  font-family: 'Montserrat',sans-serif;
}
#q-graph tr, #q-graph th, #q-graph td {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 105px;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color:#333333;
  text-align: center;
}

#q-graph td {
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

#q-graph thead tr {
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  margin: -2.5em 0 0 5em;
}

#q-graph thead th {
  width: 7.5em;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
}

#q-graph thead th.sent {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 2;
}

#q-graph thead th.paid {
  top: 2.75em;
  line-height: 2;
  left: 0;
}

#q-graph tbody tr {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 2px;
  color: #333333;
}

#q-graph #q1 {
  left: 0;
}

#q-graph #q2 {
  left: 50px;
}

#q-graph #q3 {
  left: 100px;
}

#q-graph #q4 {
  left: 150px;
  border-right: none;
}
#q-graph #q5 {
  left: 200px;
  border-right: none;
}
#q-graph #q6 {
  left: 250px;
  border-right: none;
}
#q-graph #q7 {
  left: 300px;
  border-right: none;
}
#q-graph #q8 {
  left: 350px;
  border-right: none;
}
#q-graph #q9 {
  left: 400px;
  border-right: none;
}
#q-graph #q10 {
  left: 450px;
  border-right: none;
}
#q-graph #q11 {
  left: 500px;
  border-right: none;
}
#q-graph #q12 {
  left: 550px;
  border-right: none;
}
#q-graph #q13 {
  left: 600px;
  border-right: none;
}
#q-graph #q14 {
  left: 650px;
  border-right: none;
}
#q-graph #q15 {
  left: 700px;
  border-right: none;
}
#q-graph #q16 {
  left: 750px;
  border-right: none;
}

#q-graph tbody th {
  bottom: -1.75em;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #e9d1df;
}

#q-graph .bar {
  width: 30px;
  border-bottom: none;
  color: #333333;
}

#q-graph .bar p {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: -52px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 63px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-20px);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-20px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-20px);
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-20px);
}

#q-graph .sent {
  left: 39px;
  background-color: #746a90;
  border-color: transparent;
}

#q-graph .paid {
  left: 77px;
  background-color: #746a90;
  border-color: transparent;
}
#q-graph .adele{
  background-color: #ff5247 !important;
}

#ticks {
  position: relative;
  top: -404px;
  left: 2px;
  width: 850px;
  height: 450px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: -100px;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.tick{
  height: 45px;
}
#last{
  border-bottom: 0 !important;
}
#first{
  border-top: 1px solid #3e2c38;
}
#ticks .tick {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #3e2c38;
  width: 850px;
}

#ticks .tick p {
  position: absolute;
  left: -3em;
  top: -0.8em;
  margin: 0 0 0 0.5em;
}
#one{
  max-height: 99.36%;
}
#two{
  max-height: 48.13%;
}
#three{
  max-height: 76.08%;
}
#four{
  max-height: 65.36%;
}
#five{
  max-height: 79.79%;
}
#six{
  max-height: 49.69%;
}
#seven{
  max-height: 37.19%;
}
#eight{
  max-height: 36.99%;
}
#nine{
  max-height: 28.74%
}
#ten{
  max-height: 32.17%
}
#eleven{
  max-height: 34.15%;
}
#twelve{
  max-height: 58.24%;
}
#thirteen{
  max-height: 44.14%;
}
#fourteen{
  max-height: 24.27%;
}
#fifteen{
  max-height: 36.63%;
}
#sixteen{
  max-height: 74.41%;
}
/*Second Graph*/
#q2-graph {
  display: block;
  /* fixes layout wonkiness in FF1.5 */
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 370px;
  margin: 1.1em 0 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 11px;
  z-index: 3;
}

#q2-graph tr, #q2-graph th, #q2-graph td {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 105px;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#q2-graph td {
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

#q2-graph thead tr {
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  margin: -2.5em 0 0 5em;
}

#q2-graph thead th {
  width: 7.5em;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
}

#q2-graph thead th.sent {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 2;
}

#q2-graph thead th.paid {
  top: 2.75em;
  line-height: 2;
  left: 0;
}

#q2-graph tbody tr {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 2px;
  color: #333333;
}

#q2-graph #q1 {
  left: 0;
}

#q2-graph #q2 {
  left: 50px;
}

#q2-graph #q3 {
  left: 100px;
}

#q2-graph #q4 {
  left: 150px;
  border-right: none;
}
#q2-graph #q5 {
  left: 200px;
  border-right: none;
}
#q2-graph #q6 {
  left: 250px;
  border-right: none;
}
#q2-graph tbody th {
  bottom: -1.75em;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #333333;
}

#q2-graph .bar {
  width: 30px;
  border-bottom: none;
  color: #333333 !important;
}

#q2-graph .bar p {
  color: #333333 !important;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: -95px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 150px;
  line-height: 12px;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-63px);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-63px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-63px);
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-63px);
}

#q2-graph .sent {
  left: 39px;
  background-color: #746a90;
  border-color: transparent;
}

#q2-graph .paid {
  left: 77px;
  background-color: #746a90;
  border-color: transparent;
}
#q2-graph .adele{
  background-color: #ff5247 !important;
}

#ticks2 {
  position: relative;
  top: -366px;
  left: 35px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 400px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: -100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.tick2{
  height: 60px;
}
#last{
  border-bottom: 0 !important;
}
#first{
  border-top: 1px solid #3e2c38;
}
#ticks2 .tick2 {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #3e2c38;
  width: 300px;
}

#ticks2 .tick2 p {
  position: absolute;
  left: -3em;
  top: -0.8em;
  margin: 0 0 0 0.5em;
}
#one{
  max-height: 45.1167%;
}
#two{
  max-height: 67.05%;
}
#three{
  max-height: 56.2333%;
}
#four{
  max-height: 17.1%;
}
#five{
  max-height: 37.7333%;
}
#six{
  max-height: 83.6333%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.1/animate.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.0/jquery.waypoints.js"></script>


<section id="intro"><button id="graph1">Graph #1</button>
    <button id="graph2">Graph #2</button></section>
<section id="graphs-container">
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center" id="q-fade">
        <table id="q-graph">
            <tbody>
            <tr class="qtr" id="q1">
                <th scope="row">00'</th>
                <td class="sent bar" id="one"><p class="label">NSYNC<br>No Strings Attached</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="qtr" id="q2">
                <th scope="row">01'</th>
                <td class="sent bar" id="two"><p class="label">Linkin Park<br>Hybrid Theory</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="qtr" id="q3">
                <th scope="row">02'</th>
                <td class="sent bar" id="three"><p class="label">Eminem<br>The Eminem Show</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="qtr" id="q4">
                <th scope="row">03'</th>
                <td class="sent bar" id="four"><p class="label">50 Cent<br>Get Rich or Die Tryin'</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="qtr" id="q5">
                <th scope="row">04'</th>
                <td class="sent bar" id="five"><p class="label">Usher<br>Confessions</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="qtr" id="q6">
                <th scope="row">05'</th>
                <td class="sent bar" id="six"><p class="label">Mariah Carey<br>The Emancipation of Mimi</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="qtr" id="q7">
                <th scope="row">06'</th>
                <td class="sent bar" id="seven"><p class="label">High School Musical<br>Soundtrack</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="qtr" id="q8">
                <th scope="row">07'</th>
                <td class="sent bar" id="eight"><p class="label">Josh Groban<br>Noel</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="qtr" id="q9">
                <th scope="row">08'</th>
                <td class="sent bar" id="nine"><p class="label">Lil Wayne<br>Tha Carter III</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="qtr" id="q10">
                <th scope="row">09'</th>
                <td class="sent bar" id="ten"><p class="label">Taylor Swift<br>Fearless</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="qtr" id="q11">
                <th scope="row">10'</th>
                <td class="sent bar" id="eleven"><p class="label">Eminem<br>Recovery</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="qtr" id="q12">
                <th scope="row">11'</th>
                <td class="sent bar adele" id="twelve"><p class="label">Adele<br>21</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="qtr" id="q13">
                <th scope="row">12'</th>
                <td class="sent bar adele" id="thirteen"><p class="label">Adele<br>21</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="qtr" id="q14">
                <th scope="row">13'</th>
                <td class="sent bar" id="fourteen"><p class="label">Justin Timberlake<br>20/20 Experience</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="qtr" id="q15">
                <th scope="row">14'</th>
                <td class="sent bar" id="fifteen"><p class="label">Taylor Swift<br>1989</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="qtr" id="q16">
                <th scope="row">15'</th>
                <td class="sent bar adele" id="sixteen"><p class="label">Adele<br>25</p></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!--2nd graph-->
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center" id="q2-fade">
        <table id="q2-graph">
            <tbody>
            <tr class="qtr2" id="q1">
                <th scope="row">10'</th>
                <td class="sent bar" id="one"><p class="label2">Lady Antebellum<br>Need You Now</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="qtr2" id="q2">
                <th scope="row">11'</th>
                <td class="sent bar" id="two"><p class="label2">Adele<br>21</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="qtr2" id="q3">
                <th scope="row">12'</th>
                <td class="sent bar adele" id="three"><p class="label2">Adele<br>21</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="qtr2" id="q4">
                <th scope="row">13'</th>
                <td class="sent bar" id="four"><p class="label2">Justin Timberlake<br>20/20 Experience</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="qtr2" id="q5">
                <th scope="row">14'</th>
                <td class="sent bar" id="five"><p class="label2">Various Artists<br>Frozen</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="qtr2" id="q6">
                <th scope="row">15'</th>
                <td class="sent bar adele" id="six"><p class="label2">Adele<br>25</p></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
```